# PHP display an image in two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I need help trying to display an array of images with a loop. I cant seem to get the correct path to display the image. This is my array of arrays:

```
$images = array();
$images[22] = array("id"=>22,"title" => "View of Cologne", "description" => "View of Cologne from atop the Cologne Cathedral", "country" => "Germany", "user" => "João Fernandes", "path" => "6114850721.jpg");
$images[54] = array("id"=>54,"title" => "Arch of Septimus Severus", "description" => "In the Roman Forum", "country" => "Italy", "user" => "Ellie Sullivan", "path" => "9495574327.jpg");
$images[7] = array("id"=>7,"title" => "Lunenburg Port", "description" => "On board a small sailing ship leaving Lunenburg", "country" => "Canada", "user" => "Mark Taylor", "path" => "5856697109.jpg");
$images[19] = array("id"=>19,"title" => "British Museum", "description" => "The library in the British Museum in London", "country" => "United Kingdom", "user" => "Mark Taylor", "path" => "5855729828.jpg");

$images[46] = array("id"=>46,"title" => "Temple of Hephaistos", "description" => "Located on western perimeter of Agora in Athens. Built in 460-415 BCE, it is the best preserved temple of antiquity.", "country" => "Greece", "user" => "Ellie Sullivan", "path" => "8711645510.jpg");
$images[6] = array("id"=>6,"title" => "At the top of Sulpher Mountain", "description" => "At top of Sulpher Mountain near Banff", "country" => "Canada", "user" => "Frantisek Wichterlová", "path" => "6114907897.jpg");


?>
```

the images are stored locally in a file called travel in my PHP workspace. What would be the correct way to loop through the array, get "path", and display that image?

Thank you

Comment: Am I correct in assuming the images are stored in the folder named 'travel'? Do you want to output HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing incredible:

```
$basepath = './travel/';
foreach ($images as $image) {
    printf('<img src="%s"/>', $basepath . $image['path']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use foreach like that:

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo $image['path'];

}
```